# Simple for loop suddenly crashes program in C

Tags: c, loops, modulo

I am using MSVC via

```
cl file.c
```

with this very simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int
main(void) {
    
    int num = 50, pointNum = 60, max = 0;
    
    puts("Hello");

    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", pointNum % i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when I run it from the commandline, it just pauses and then crashes, only printing "Hello". I have no clue what is wrong, because it seems error free.

Comment: Could you describe why you believe it crashes? Does it print some text to the screen? If so, could you share that text?

Comment: @BillLynch I don't know why it crashes. It only prints "Hello" (the put statement), but pauses at the loop and then crashes.

Comment: Right, does it print nothing? Does it print the string "segmentation fault"? Does it print the string "Hi I crashed!"?

Comment: @BillLynch It didn't print the string segmentation fault, probably because I just use Notepad++ and the commandline. So I had no clue.

Comment: you start a loop with `i` equal to `0` and then the first thing you do in the loop is to divide by `i`... so you are dividing by zero... it's not so error free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `i == 0`, you perform the math `60 % 0` which triggers division by zero. That triggers undefined behavior which often will crash your program.

Comment: It causes undefined behaviour - any other result is possible too

Answer (score 1):

In the very first iteration of the loop, the divisor is 0. But division by 0 is not possible. Thus, it simply crashes. Instead of this code snippet, I think you should use

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", pointNum % i);
}
```

This will not provide any error.